# Prove $(\overline{A \cap B}) \subseteq \overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $\overline{A}$ be the closure of $A$. My attempt:

Since $A \subseteq \overline{A}$ and $B \subseteq \overline{B}$,  we have
$$A \cap B \subseteq \overline{A} \cap \overline{B}.$$
Since $\overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$ is closed, it follows that
$$ \overline{A \cap B} \subseteq \overline{A} \cap \overline{B}.$$

Is this a valid approach?

Comment: Just to clarify: is $\overline x$ the closure or the complement of $x$? Oh, $A\subset \overline A$, so I guess its the closure.

Comment: You found a very elegant proof. Looks good.

Comment: Has to be closure, but @mathjacks should make clear in the question that he means closure.

Comment: Sorry, it does mean closure. I've fixed that.

Comment: Good proof. In general whenever hou need to prove that the closure of a set is included in a closed set, try to prove the initial set is included in that closed set

Comment: I agree with Umberto, although it is a known proof :P