# counterexample for $\overline{A \cap B} = \overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

[Prove $(\overline{A \cap B}) \subseteq \overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1149655/prove-overlinea-cap-b-subseteq-overlinea-cap-overlineb)

But the same relation with a $=$ isn't always true. Can someone find an example where the $=$ doesn't hold, I can't seem to find one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let $A=\mathbb{Q}$ and $B=\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$, then $\overline{A\cap B} =\varnothing$ while $\overline{A}=\overline{B}=\mathbb{R}$, so $\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The obvious thing to try is a case where $A\cap B$ is empty, but they share some limit points. Can you think of such an example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $A=(0,1)$ and $B=(1,2)$.  Then $A\cap B=\emptyset$ so the LHS is empty.  But the RHS equals $\{1\}$ since $\overline A=[0,1]$ and $\overline B=[1,2]$.