# Example that $\overline{A \cup B} \supseteq \overline A\cup \overline B$ is not true

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I struggle finding an example to show $\overline{A \cup B} \supseteq \overline A\cup \overline B$ is not true. Any hints?

Comment: Are you sure such an example must exist?

Comment: yes because $\overline{A \cap B}$ is the smallest set in a metric space, which contains ${A \cap B}$ and the following is true for $\overline{A \cap B} \subseteq \overline A\cap \overline B$

Comment: Just because $X\subseteq Y$, that doesn't mean $Y\subseteq X$ is impossible...

Comment: Can u prove that its always like u assume?

Comment: The user drhab already did.

Comment: my bad I used $\cup$ instead of $\cap$. Should I start a new question?

Comment: Yes, a new question would be best since you already got an answer to this one.

Comment: Actually I don't want to get flagged for double posting.

Comment: Edits to a question should be used to *clarify* the question, not to change it into a completely different question (which is not fair to those users that correctly answer the original question). You should accept the answer you got here, and ask a new question.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1776768/counterexample-for-overlinea-cap-b-overlinea-cap-overlineb?rq=1 before you repost - I think it answers your question regarding $\cap$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't find any example, since it is true.

From $A\cup B\supseteq A$ it follows that $\overline{A\cup B}\supseteq\overline A$.

From $A\cup B\supseteq B$ it follows that $\overline{A\cup B}\supseteq \overline{B}$.

Then consequently $$\overline{A\cup B}\supseteq\overline A\cup\overline B$$

Comment: Let it be that $A=(0,1)$ and $B=(1,2)$. Then the $A\cap B=\varnothing$ so that $\overline{A\cap B}=\varnothing$.  But the $\overline A\cap\overline B=\{1\}$ so is not a subset of $\overline{A\cap B}$

Comment: Can you explain why $\overline{A}$ contains $0$ and $1$? I just don't see it from the general definition. I think its because they are the limit points or accumulation points but how can I know that it is a limit point?

Comment: The comment concerns $\mathbb R$ equipped with its (usual) Euclidean topology. In that topological space $1$ and $0$ are [limitpoints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point#Definition) of $(0,1)$ hence are elements of its closure. You can observe that $1$ is a limitpoint by noting that every open set that contains $1$ will have a non-empty intersection with $(0,1)$. Actually if $1$ would not belong to the closure of $(0,1)$ then it would belong to the complement of that closure which is an open set that has an empty intersection with $(0,1)$. This is not the case.