# Proving $ \overline{E \cup F} = \overline {E} \cup \overline{F}$ and $ \overline{E \cap F} \subset \overline {E} \cap \overline{F}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

Let $E, F \subset X$, prove that $ \overline{E \cup F} = \overline {E} \cup \overline{F}$.

For further clarification: I'm referring to $\overline{E}$ as E closure. E' would be the limit point, defined as $E' = \{ ( E \cap N_r (p) ) \backslash \{p\} \neq \emptyset , \ \  \forall R >0 \}$. This is also in a topological space.

I proved it as follows:

> $\overline{E \cup F} = \overline{E \cup E' \cup F \cup F'}$
>   $\\ = \overline{(E \cup E') \cup (F \cup F')}$
>   $\\ = \overline{(E \cup E')} \cup \overline{(F \cup F')}$
>   $\\ = \overline{(E)} \cup \overline{F}$

The next one is a little tricky for me. Prove $ \overline{E \cap F} \subset \overline {E} \cap \overline{F}$. Here's my go at it:

> Let $x \in \overline{E \cap F}$. Then $x \in \overline{ (E \cup E') \cap (F \cup F)} \rightarrow x \in \overline{E} \cap \overline{F}. $

Feedback would be much appreciated! I've also been trying to come up with examples that would help me visualize these statements a little better.

Comment: is $\overline{A}$ closure? how do you define it?

Comment: Sorry, yes! The overline indicates closure.

Comment: I presume this is meant to be in a topological space?  You really should say so if it is.

Comment: @Nikitau, how do you define it?

Comment: @janmarqz I'm defining E closure as the set of limit points, E', where $E' = \{ ( E \cap N_r (p) ) \backslash \{p\} \neq \emptyset , \ \  \forall R >0 \}$.

Comment: @MitchellSpector Yes I did mean for it to be in a topological space. I will edit my post to reflect this!

Comment: @Nikitau, perhaps you are meaning $\overline{E}=E\cup E'$.

Comment: @janmarqz Yes, thank you! Sorry. I get very clumsy and overlook things with Latex.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** We have $\overline{E\cup F}=E\cup F\cup (E\cup F)'$, but if you can do
$$(E\cup F)'=E'\cup F',$$
then you can get $\overline{E\cup F}=E\cup E'\cup F\cup F'$, so $\overline{E\cup F}=\overline{E}\cup\overline{F}$.

Comment: Ah, I think I got it. Just to make sure I'm not wrong: I made use of the rule $ A \cap (B \cup C) = A \cap B \cup A \cap C$. Thank you for the hint!

Comment: for the "union" property, this rule you mention is not employed

Answer (score 0):

To prove that $\overline{E \cap F} \subset \overline{E} \cap \overline{F}$:

Let $x \in \overline{E \cap F}$. There exists $(x_n)_n \subset E \cap F$ such that $x_n \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow} x$.

$(x_n)_n \subset E \cap F$ means that $(x_n)_n \subset E$ and also that $(x_n)_n \subset F$. Can you finish this?

Comment: Sorry, how do we know that $ \exists (x_n)_n$ such that $x_n \rightarrow_{n\rightarrow \infty} x$?

Comment: It is equivalent: $x \in \overline{E} \Longleftrightarrow \exists (x_n)_n \subset E$ such that $x_n \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow} x$.


I thought of clarifying this as I didn't know whether or not you knew about this, sorry.

Comment: You can find another proof of this inclusion in this link: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1149655/prove-overlinea-cap-b-subseteq-overlinea-cap-overlineb?rq=1.
This uses that the closure of a set is the "smallest" closet set that contains such set.